# How can I sort a money (I used VARCHAR) from lowest value to highest in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Whenever I use `ORDER BY {column name} ASC`, it won't accurately display what I want it to display.

```
8,000.00
132,453.00
```

it will show:

```
132, 453.00
8,000.00
```

even if it's `ASC`. If i change the data type to `Decimal`.. i will lose the commas. Help!

Comment: Change the data type of your column. That is the best solution.

Comment: would you mind sharing the query?

Comment: SELECT AccountNumber
,CONVERT(varchar, CAST(AvailableBalance AS money), 1) AS AvailableBalance
FROM Account
WHERE (AccountType LIKE 'Savings' AND SiteCode LIKE '120')
ORDER BY AvailableBalance ASC
GO

Comment: Tip: Include the DDL for the table and your query when posting SQL questions. That way we don't have to guess of ask pesky questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CAST(AvailableBalance AS money)
```

otherwise your ordering is alphabetic so '1' comes before '8'

Comment: thanks, man! it worked! sorry im still noob. i appreciate this!